# Is the error reporting in Collectors.toMap() broken?

Tags: java, java-stream

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("3","55","3");
Map<String,Integer> map = strings
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(s ->s, s -> s.length()));
```

returns

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key 1
```

where I would expect Duplicate key 3

Comment: Replicated with 1.8.0u152. It seems to log the `HashMap$Node`'s `value` instead of its `key`...

Comment: notice that if you do `Collectors.toMap(s ->s, s ->4)`, you get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key 4`, so it seems it is actually complaining about the value being duplicate

Comment: See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8173464

Comment: @Zircon interestingly, the bug your link to is marked as duplicate for [8040892](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8040892), which itself claims to be fixed. See also other duplicate [8178142](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8178142). Mah.

Comment: @Mena and the duplicate reference shows "Fix Version/s: 9" - It was not fixed until Java 9.

Comment: @Zircon ah yes :) Fair enough then... You could pack all that into an answer!

Answer (score 2):

This was fixed in Java 9. Now the error message is correct:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key 3 (attempted merging values 1 and 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems, like this was a bug in JDK 8 but is no longer the case as of JDK 9. Reason one being that I cannot replicate it on JDK 9 and reason two [this link](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8173464) provided by @Zircon derives about the issue and it being fixed as of JDK 9.

Seems like there have been several posts about this issue, another link being:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8040892

which itself is a duplicate of few other posts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's a bug but there is another way of converting this into a map which is by using identity function:

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("3","55","3");
Map<String, List<String>> map = strings.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), Arrays::asList));
```

By doing this you will get correct error which is

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key [3]
```

For array with unique values

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("3","55","4");
```

result would be

```
{55=[55], 3=[3], 4=[4]}
```

Comment: That will correctly report duplicate keys, but not produce the intended result when there is no conflict.

Comment: @Holger Agreed after posting the answer I noticed that btw thanks for pointing it out.